# Adding an ICON to a link field

Tags: 8, navigation

I want to create a link field to a page on the Apple iStore. I develop iPhone apps and I want an Apple Store icon to display instead of the link text.  Ideally, I would like to have a rollover effect. I was thinking that I could add a class to do this, but it seems like there should be a simpler way or perhaps a module.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! It's not clear what you mean by _simpler than adding a CSS class_, also because if you are going to do it yourself, you need to add CSS classes. Requests for modules are off-topic for us, in the same way they are for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I used the [Link-Icon][1] field.

did almost exactly what I wanted. There are hover effects, adjust where the field will go. All of the ICONs are the [fontawsome.io][2] catalog...


  [1]: https://www.drupal.org/project/linkicon
  [2]: http://fontawesome.io/

worked with bootstrap 3 theme.